# What's wrong with a DailyMotion tag?

Tags: support, tags

So via a convoluted email chain, I found out that there's a thing called [DailyMotion](http://www.dailymotion.com). And that they have [an API](http://www.dailymotion.com/developer). And that folks are [asking questions about this on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=dailymotion).

And then I found out that this place has actual *people* working for them, who want to *answer* some of these questions... "Aha!" you say, "The plot thickens!"

See, one of 'em thought it'd be a good idea to create a tag to help keep tabs on these. Which is, you gotta admit, kind of an obvious idea - after all, it's one of the relatively few things tags are actually *good for*.

Then [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/22948367/revisions) happened. And [this](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3226265/revisions). So now I'm scratching my head. **What am I missing here?** This isn't one of those crazy tags like [cowboy-bob-please-answer-this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cowboy-bob-please-answer-this) or someone slapping tags for their product on questions about a competitors or even a meta tag; it's literally just *the name of the product the question is being asked about*.

(I'm bringing this up here on the off-chance that there's some background I'm missing, and also so that *no one* gets the idea that they need to email us privately to get their tags created.)

Comment: It's poorly named, but that's a reason to fix the naming, not to nuke it...

Comment: At a glance, it feels like a meta tag. If there is an API involved, that would be useful for editors to know. If that information was added to the tag wiki, and perhaps if the tag was renamed to something like 'dailymotion-api' it would have a better chance of survival.

Comment: Looks like a generic inane "let me add a random (but seemingly related) tag so I can net 2 rep points" kind of edit to me. Others documented [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/217932/where-do-we-draw-the-line-on-esoteric-tag-additions)

Comment: You make a good point, @George - maybe we should revisit [this proposal](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/129624/promote-tag-wiki-creation-for-new-tags/131917#131917).

Comment: I agree with George that [tag:dailymotion-api] would be a better name for the tag, and even on the [first example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22948367/retrieving-dailymotion-popular-ideos), probably the *only* tag that should even be on the question. The other tags are far worse. "trend"? "popularity"? We should be discussing whether *those* should exist.

Comment: @GeorgeCummins you're possibly right about *-api being a better (more precise) name, but it seems like a huge stretch to call it a meta tag.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think it's a combination of several points:

- [dailymotion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dailymotion) looks like a brand tag rather than a product tag. [dailymotion-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dailymotion-api) would be clearer in this respect.
- “Dailymotion” is more famous as a website than as an API. It is not at all clear that “I want to scrape dailymotion.com” warrants a specific tag, whereas “I want to use the Dailymotion API” definitely warrants a tag.
- Like all other forms of reviews (of suggested edits, of close votes, etc.), people who monitor tag creation often don't do the job seriously. Whether they're badge-hunting or genuinely animated by a will to make the site better, they often don't spend any time investigating and just pick one option based on incomplete information.

The questions you cite are pretty mediocre, which doesn't invite spending much time thinking about them. Still, [removing `dailymotion` and keeping `for-loop`](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/3226265/revisions) is really silly.

There is now a [dailymotion-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dailymotion-api) tag with a starter-class tag wiki. I have only used it on one mediocre question, please apply it to other relevant questions.

Comment: I was one of the people who requested the tag , so thanks for all your help and answers :) We hope this tag will help to have more interesting questions as we advertised it on our website.

Answer (score 12):

Per Shog's request, I'm chiming in here.

Sorry for taking so long to respond, and apologies for any confusion I seem to have caused.

**The short answer is:**  I seem to have been overzealous and screwed up.

I'm trying to remember back that far, and if I recall correctly there was a *rash* of typoed tags and ridiculous Suggested Edit approvals, and I went through and rolled back or edited some of those questions.

If I also recall correctly, the first question was the only question tagged at with [dailymotion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dailymotion) at the time.  I had some reason for removing it, but I don't remember what that reason was.  When it popped up again a short time later, it came with this tag wiki (which really should have been rejected as "Wiki not helpful"):

> Build great applications using the Dailymotion API and bring Dailymotion content and functionalities to your users through your application or website.

Not the greatest tag wiki in the world, and since it was from an extremely low-rep user, I figured it was some sort of advertising.  And as others have mentioned, the tag [dailymotion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dailymotion) didn't really seem appropriate, and [dailymotion-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dailymotion-api) would have been a better fit.

I do remember going to look up what Daily Motion actually *was*, but I got distracted by something and never came back and to consider creating a [dailymotion-api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/dailymotion-api) tag for those questions, and then forgot about it entirely until I got pinged just now.

If I caused any confusion for the Daily Motion people, or gave them the perception of a hostile environment, I apologize, as that was not my intentions.  I try to do my best to help maintain the site, but it appears I whiffed here.